# CORS issue when loading third party website in iframe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to load a partner website inside an iframe. Our partner already set a CORS policy allowing our url's. However, when I set the src on the iframe to the url, the iframe stays empty in Chrome/Edge. It Firefox in works. I don't see any obvious errors in the console. Only Edge gives a warning in the response header Set-Cookie that SameSite wasn't set, but our partner indicated they set it to SameSite=None.

Our partner did point out that they read the 'origin' header from the request I send for the url's and check those against our policy. This header is automatically set by the browser, but not when I load the url in the iframe. I tried adding the referrerPolicy attribute with value 'origin' but that doesn't set the origin in the request header.

**Is it possible to make the request set the origin header from the iframe?**

This is the minimum reproducable example from the code. I left out a call to the dataservice which creates a token based on a certificate. This part works, because if I open the resulting uri in a separate browser window, the partner website opens. It's just the iframe in Chrome/Edge that's giving issues.

```
const App = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit() {
    // {...} Call to dataservice that creates a token for the parameter
    var token = "123";
    // Set the partner website with token
    var uri = "https://example.com/?token=" + token;
    setSrc(uri);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click</button>

        <iframe
          title="example iframe"
          width="100%"
          height="400"
          referrerPolicy="origin"
          src={src}
        >
        </iframe>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the third party website was way outdated to support modern browsers and this had nothing to do with CORS issues. The settings and CORS policy we setup was correct. The partner website needs to be updated in order to work with iframes in modern browsers. Previously it was only used in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is that you are creating the iframe with an empty string since src is empty when you render your component. How about you add a useEffect hook and add src to your dependency array, this will cause your component to re-render when the value of src changes. Something similar to this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("Hi, I'm rendering")
  }, [src])

  function handleSubmit() {
    // {...} Call to dataservice that creates a token for the parameter
    var token = "123";
    // Set the partner website with token
    var uri = "https://example.com/?token=" + token;
    setSrc(uri);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Click</button>

        <iframe
          title="example iframe"
          width="100%"
          height="400"
          referrerPolicy="origin"
          src={src}
        >
        </iframe>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but with the same result of an empty iframe. When I use the example.com website it loads with or without the useEffect. I know it's got something to do with CORS because the iframe works in Firefox, but not in Chrome/Edge.